# FF 37 Ntlm not working

Tags: firefox

I am using 14.10 
I just upgraded my FF from 33 to 37.  I have a timecard system at work that uses NTLMv1

I have set network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1 to true
I get the Authentication Required pop up box, but it will not accept my name/password

This was working fine in FF 33.  I dusted off my old Windoze box, and it works fine.

Anyone else having problems with this?
Any Ideas what to do?

Thank You,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set listed parameters to **True** and now auth works.

```
network.auth.force-generic-ntlm
network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter your URL as value of preference: network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris.
It worked for me on FF 37 Ubuntu 14.10. I guess that a comma separated list may be entered too.

Answer (score 0):

I have set only **network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1** to **true** and now NTLMv1 authentication works on sites and proxie.

I think, this occurs, because parameter **network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1** was renamed to **network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1** ([bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=423758#c50))